# How to set internal environment with public cloud service?

Tags: azure, networking, dns, kubernetes, azure-aks

For Microsoft Azure cloud, with AKS service, we want to deploy an internal application that can been accessed only by our team.

This scenario:

- Use public domain myawesomesite.com for production.
- Use subdomain internal.myawesomesite.com for staging. (Limit access)

Even use [private DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/private-dns-getstarted-powershell) can only connect the virtual network vms.

Then how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this is the right solution:

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/examples/whitelist

If use [nginx-ingress](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress), install with this setting:

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress \
    --set controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an Internal Load Balancer (ILB) in Azure, which is just like a regular load balancer but with only private IP's from the same VNET where AKS is deployed (thus, no public IP's). It uses the annotation:

`annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"`

as described in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb). You can use AzureDNS to point an A record to an that IP.

Answer (score -2):

It's a solution with Calico on AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/calico.html